# Method Overloading ambiguous

Tags: java, overloading

I'm currently reviewing for OCA exam and thought int/float method would work on the third test.

In OCA Study Guide of Jeane Boyarsky only says 4 order rules to choose the right overloaded method.

1. Exact match by type
2. Larger primitive type
3. Autoboxed type
4. Varargs

Can someone explain why java says it's ambiguous?

```
public static void main(String... args){
    OverLoadingMethod ov=new OverLoadingMethod();
    ov.test(1F,2);
    ov.test(1,2F);
    ov.test(1,2);
}
public void test(float i,int j){
    System.out.println("float/int");        
}

public void test(int i,float j){
    System.out.println("int/float"); 
}
public void test(float i,float j){
    System.out.println("float/float");
}
```

Produces this error

```
OverLoadingMethod.java:12: error: reference to test is ambiguous
        ov.test(1,2);
          ^
  both method test(float,int) in OverLoadingMethod and method test(int,float) in OverLoadingMethod match
```

Comment: which method do **you** think it should call? Why?

Comment: I thought it should call test(int,float) though test(float,int) would work. compiler should prioritize the first valid parameter which is int. then convert the second parameter to float by Rule #2

Comment: *compiler should prioritize the first valid parameter* - where is that stated?

Comment: @Javajansen "compiler should" who says it should?

Comment: It's just my thought. that's how my brain will work if I'm a compiler.

Comment: we would all be out of work if compilers behaved like our brains ;-)

Comment: @ScaryWombat  if java can intelligently choose the right one between those 2  methods java will evolve into a new generation compiler.anyways if this appears on the exam, I already got the idea. thanks for the inputs guys. cheers!

Comment: Why should the compiler prioritize the first parameter? In which regard is the first parameter better than the other? If such a rule existed, wouldn’t it be just another rule that programmers had to learn?

Answer (score 4):

None of the overloads take two ints.

So, one of the ints has to be widened to a float. But which one? An overload exists where the float is the first parameter, and another overload exists where the float is the second.

Which should be picked? Which is *objectively better*? Neither is, according to the rules the language spec.  Hence ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Java automatically casts int into float since there is no loss of precision.

Thus your `test(1,2)` can be interpreted as two float arguments, one float - one int, and one int - one float also. Thus it's ambiguous for the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

For `ov.test(1,2)`, both `test(int i,float j)` and `test(float i,int j)` are accessible and applicable. Then the compiler needs to choose the most specific one, while any of them is not specific enough, so compiler error happens.

The whole complete choosing procedure is descirbed in [java language specification 15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2)